# Star revolving a star

Tags: exoplanet, star-systems

Are there any star system(planet system) where a star revolves around a star? Is it theoretically possible?

Comment: Have you done any research before asking? You should read [ask].

Comment: @J.Chomel I am new to this ,thanks,  found the answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52628/could-there-be-a-star-orbiting-around-a-planet

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is about the existence of [binary star](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_star).

There are many binary stars in the universe. They are in fact more common  than single stars. Here are [interesting explanations](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-binary-stars-more-common-than-single-stars) for the latest.